# Errors when handling multiple topics, publishers and subscribers + WSO2MB

Tags: java, wso2, jmeter, messagebroker, wso2-message-broker

I've got the `Message Broker 3.1.0`, and I'm trying to publish messages through a java program and subscribe through the `JMeter` script which I'm running it in headless mode in Windows.

So in my case I've got three topics added in the MB,three different java classes being executed through cmd in order to publishes messages and three different subscribers created through JMeter GUI. I'm hereby providing the [url](http://pastebin.com/WHQ8YTgq) for one of the jmx file which has been generated through the `JMeter` GUI. To my knowledge the following properties have been changed in all three jmx files:

- name="jms.provider_url
- name="jms.topic"

I created 3 different `jndi.property` files for each of the subscribers having the following properties:

- connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory =
  amqp://admin:admin@clientID/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5672'
- topic.Games = Games (I changed only this for the other two topics as
  well, ie: the topic name)

Once I start publishing and subscribing all three, i'm running into following errors.

> INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.protocol.AMQProtocolEngine} -  Closing channel due to: org.wso2.andes.AMQInternalException: An Exclusive Bindings already exists for different topic. Not permitted. [error code 541: internal error]
>   INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.exchange.TopicExchange} -  Message routing key: Games No routes.
>   [2016-05-19 16:38:13,953]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.MessagePreProcessor} -  Message routing key: Games No routes in cluster. Ignoring Message id

I can understand that some property/properties on the jmx files have been duplicated or referring to the same thing in all the three files. Where could I've gone wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this sorted out by changing the `jms.durableSubscriptionId` and `jms.clientId` into different ids' in all three jmx files.